# What is causing this code/command to not work when comparing negative numbers?

Tags: awk

```
awk '($6>max) && ($4!="AZ") {max = $6; line = $0}END{print line}' foo.txt
```

Whenever field #6 contains negative numbers, it doesn't correctly return the line that has the highest number in field 6.

The goal is to for example in the following file contents:

```bash
Shellstrop Eleanor Phoenix AZ 85023 -2920765
Shellstrop Donna Tarantula_Springs NV 89047 -5920765
Mendoza Jason Jacksonville FL 32205 -4123794
Mendoza Douglas Jacksonville FL 32209 -3193274 (Donkey Doug)
Peleaz Steven Jacksonville FL 32203 -3123794 (Pillboi)
```

goal is to return the line containing Peleaz. (It wouldn't be `Shellstrop Eleanor` as she lives in `AZ`.) Instead it returns a newline

This works as required for positive numbers but not negative. So I don't understand, surely if it works for positive numbers it can't be completely wrong.
Or there could be some completely different bug Im missing. Im very new to awk.

```bash
awk '($6>max) && ($4!="AZ") {max = $6; line = $0}END{print line}' foo.txt
```

Expected line with `Peleaz Steven Jacksonville` to return. Returns newline instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must also check for condition when `max` is not set:

```bash
awk '
(max == "" || $6 > max) && $4 != "AZ" {
   max = $6
   line = $0
}
END {
   print line
}' file

Peleaz Steven Jacksonville FL 32203 -3123794 (Pillboi)
```

Comment: Still getting incorrect input. Why is it outputting values with field of AZ still?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad: That has been taken care of. You can see generated output now with `FL` record.